# Android XPath index issue

Tags: java, android, testing, xpath, appium

Very new to Android Testing.
I came across this Xpath

```
xpath: (//android.widget.ImageView[1])[3]
```

I know that in ImageView[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIaxR.png) "1" is the index of the element.
What is [3] here???

**Update:**

I am running a test (mobile App). The above XPath is to tap on the Bell icon.
It did tap on the bell icon perfectly.
But today when I run my test it doesn't tap on the Bell icon instead it taps on the user Profile Picture.

[image]

Using appium I found the xpath of the Bell icon as below:

```
xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageView
```

Now when I use this new xpath the Bell icon is clicked.

Are both the Xpaths same?? 
Why is this new xpath so long? is there a way to shorten this??
Any kind of help is really Appreciated!!!

Comment: `[3]` is *occurrence* number

Comment: @JaSON Please check my updated question. Would really appreciate your input on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the absolute xpath using the appium(which you have stated above) and the one you are using like //android.widget.ImageView[1])[3] is the relative xpath of the icon.

Absolute xpath :  It is the path from the root element to the particular element.
Relative xpath : It is the reference path of the element or particular path to the element.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `//android.widget.ImageView[1]` selects every `android.widget.ImageView` that is the first child of its parent. This will in general select a set of nodes. The `[3]` selects the third node in this set.

Comment: Thank you. Please check my updated question. Would really appreciate your input on that.

Comment: Sorry, your new question is outside my area of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access bell button using class name.

(//*[@class="Class name"])[2]

```
  (//*[@class="android.widget.ImageView"])[2]
```